# Differences between Mit scheme 9.1 and 9.2

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I am using Ubuntu 16. From the software archive I get MIT scheme 9.1. Is it
worth to install the version 9.2 manually?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release changes](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/release.html) there ar *no important enough changes to state them* between 9.1 and 9.2. MIT Scheme is a R5RS and it's very unlikely that any version will not work if you keep to the R5RS standard and keep away from underspecifications.

There are lots of alternatives to MIT Scheme. I currently use [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/) since it has a nice IDE interface, macroexpander tools and a debugger. You can switch between `#!r5rs`, `#!r6rs`, [`#!r7rs` (yeah!)](https://github.com/lexi-lambda/racket-r7rs), and rackets own language  `#lang racket` making it very suitable for most needs.

Comment: Special thanks for the link to the relevant web-side! When I tried to google to find an answer for my question, I found always the html-pages of the reference.

Comment: Happy to help @GeorgFuss. If you think this answered your question you can consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/232765). Happy new year!